# pigpio daemon inactive, even though connection still exists

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, gpio

i'm using the pigpio library with a raspberry pi 3 model B+, the latest version of Raspbian and python 2.7. On the pi is running uWSGI and nginx. I'm also using flask.

#### Important info at bottom under *EDIT*

I've got a problem with the pigpio daemon. If i start the daemon after boot,

```
systemctl status pigpio
```

outputs the following:

```
pigpiod.service - Daemon required to control GPIO pins via pigpio
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pigpiod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I'm pretty new to all this, but it seems to be not ok.
After that i import pipgio in python and connect to the daemon (i was just trying. Never expected, that it would work). The command

```
pigpio.pi().connected
```

outputs *True*. That seems to be ok, quite apart from the fact that the daemon is not active. If i type

```
pigpio.pi().stop()
```

, the connection is still active. This behaviour i don't understand.
My question is, if i missunderstand the usage of the library.
In addition, the real reason for this post is, that i want to control GPIO's. For that i've written the following code.

```
import pigpio
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
from smbus2 import SMBus
import serial

@app.route("/forward/")
def forward():
    try:
        status = 0
        endstatus = 1

        while endstatus == 1:
            response = "3"

            if response == "2":
                status = int(response)
            elif response == "1":
                status = int(response)
            elif response == "3":
                status = int(response)

            # print(status)

            if status == 3:
                GPIO.output(Input3A, True)
                GPIO.output(Input4A, True)
                servo = 3
                pi = pigpio.pi()
                pi.set_mode(servo, pigpio.OUTPUT)
                pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(servo, 1300)

            if status == 1:
                GPIO.output(Input3A, False)
                GPIO.output(Input4A, False)
                pi = pigpio.pi()
                servo = 3
                pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(servo, 1500)
                pi.stop()
                endstatus = 0

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pi = pigpio.pi()
        all_off()
        pi.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

With that code i can run it only once. If i click on the the corresponding button to execute the try block again, nothing happens. After that the uWSGI-log outputs:

```
(venv) root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/arc# tail /var/log/uwsgi/test_app_uwsgi.log 
  File "/home/pi/arc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/pi/arc/movement.py", line 90, in forward
    pi.set_mode(servo, pigpio.OUTPUT)
  File "/home/pi/arc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pigpio.py", line 1340, in set_mode
    return _u2i(_pigpio_command(self.sl, _PI_CMD_MODES, gpio, mode))
  File "/home/pi/arc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pigpio.py", line 989, in _pigpio_command
    sl.s.send(struct.pack('IIII', cmd, p1, p2, 0))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
[pid: 321|app: 0|req: 2/2] 127.0.0.1 () {50 vars in 901 bytes} [Sun Jan  6 14:39:40 2019] GET /forward/ => generated 0 bytes in 170 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

and

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Can't connect to pigpio at localhost(8888)

Did you start the pigpio daemon? E.g. sudo pigpiod

Did you specify the correct Pi host/port in the environment
variables PIGPIO_ADDR/PIGPIO_PORT?
E.g. export PIGPIO_ADDR=soft, export PIGPIO_PORT=8888

Did you specify the correct Pi host/port in the
pigpio.pi() function? E.g. pigpio.pi('soft', 8888)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

I think it could be a port problem. But i didn't get the pigpio daemon configured to listen on i.e. port 8889. Starting with `pigpiod -p 8889 start` seems not to be enough.

If i try to start the daemon with the following command `sudo pigpio -l -n 127.0.0.1` the uWSGI log outputs:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Can't connect to pigpio at localhost(8888)

Did you start the pigpio daemon? E.g. sudo pigpiod

Did you specify the correct Pi host/port in the environment
variables PIGPIO_ADDR/PIGPIO_PORT?
E.g. export PIGPIO_ADDR=soft, export PIGPIO_PORT=8888

Did you specify the correct Pi host/port in the
pigpio.pi() function? E.g. pigpio.pi('soft', 8888)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
[pid: 320|app: 0|req: 2/2] 127.0.0.1 () {52 vars in 994 bytes} [Sun Jan  6 14:53:49 2019] GET / => generated 770 bytes in 5 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 80 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 320|app: 0|req: 3/3] 127.0.0.1 () {48 vars in 846 bytes} [Sun Jan  6 14:59:50 2019] GET / => generated 766 bytes in 8 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 80 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 320|app: 0|req: 4/4] 127.0.0.1 () {52 vars in 994 bytes} [Sun Jan  6 14:59:50 2019] GET / => generated 766 bytes in 8 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 80 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
/home/pi/arc/movement.py:54: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(Input1A, GPIO.OUT)
/home/pi/arc/movement.py:58: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(Input1B, GPIO.OUT)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Can't connect to pigpio at localhost(8888)

Can't create callback thread.
Perhaps too many simultaneous pigpio connections.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/arc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/pi/arc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/pi/arc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/pi/arc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/pi/arc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/pi/arc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/pi/arc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/pi/arc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/pi/arc/movement.py", line 90, in forward
    pi.set_mode(servo, pigpio.OUTPUT)
  File "/home/pi/arc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pigpio.py", line 1340, in set_mode
    return _u2i(_pigpio_command(self.sl, _PI_CMD_MODES, gpio, mode))
  File "/home/pi/arc/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pigpio.py", line 989, in _pigpio_command
    sl.s.send(struct.pack('IIII', cmd, p1, p2, 0))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
[pid: 320|app: 0|req: 5/5] 127.0.0.1 () {50 vars in 901 bytes} [Sun Jan  6 15:02:38 2019] GET /forward/ => generated 0 bytes in 165 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 0 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

I did a lot of research, but i'm stuck.

#### EDIT:

I've more information now. After a lot of test i found out, that the main problem is, that i can't execute a python script with pigpio imported twice. The script will be executed via uwsgi, nginx and flask. It's a simple button on a website, which redirects via ajax to the script on the pi.
After the first execution the script does what is shall do. But if i then execute another script with pigpio and so on imported i get the following error:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Can't connect to pigpio at localhost(8888)

Can't create callback thread.
Perhaps too many simultaneous pigpio connections.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "motor_stopp.py", line 37, in <module>
    all_off()
  File "motor_stopp.py", line 21, in all_off
    pi.set_mode(servo, pigpio.OUTPUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1296, in set_mode
    return _u2i(_pigpio_command(self.sl, _PI_CMD_MODES, gpio, mode))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 983, in _pigpio_command
    sl.s.send(struct.pack('IIII', cmd, p1, p2, 0))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

If i then *restart* uwsgi with `kill -HUP pid` i can start another python script. Now, i could restart uwsgi every time, after a code block. It seems that this would solve my problem. But that's not really a solution.

Could it be, that uwsgi and pigpio uses the same port?
And if so, how can i change the port on one of the libraries?

Comment: 1) I would suggest you edit and shorten your post, the title does not seem to be inline with the question you are try to asking? I don't know what exactly the question you are trying to ask? 2) if your script works without uwsig and nginx, then it probably has nothing to do with your code. the question will be what is your uWSGI setting and nginx and deemon setting? 3) I know pigpiod by default is running port 8888 for sure as per its doc. 4) I suggest you post at [Raspberry Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) where the developer of pigpio Joan is a very active participant.